# Check value checkbox inside handler event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the value of a checkbox inside an handler event called by .on event binded on itself.

```
 $("#mytweetswitch").on('change',this.checkTweets);



   checkTweets: function(){

     //here I need to get isChecked of #mytweetswitch 


   },
```

Comment: `isChecked = $(this).prop('checked');`

Comment: @KingKing I think you accidentally hit the comment button rather than the answer button :)

Comment: What's wrong with `this.checked`?

Answer (score 1):

```
checkTweets: function() {
    return $(this).is(':checked');
}
```